# Assert.AreEqual raises an exception when comparing two IEnumerable objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

The Moq input list for target Method is

```
var moqReturn = new List<Text>()
{
    new Text() {Id = 0, SenderId = 3, ReceiverId = 5},
    new Text() {Id = 1, SenderId = 5, ReceiverId = 1},
    new Text() {Id = 2, SenderId = 1, ReceiverId = 5},
    new Text() {Id = 3, SenderId = 3, ReceiverId = 5},
    new Text() {Id = 4, SenderId = 3, ReceiverId = 5},
    new Text() {Id = 5, SenderId = 5, ReceiverId = 4},
    new Text() {Id = 6, SenderId = 5, ReceiverId = 4},
    new Text() {Id = 7, SenderId = 5, ReceiverId = 10}
};
```

The method under the test is: given userId = 5, top = 3, start = 0

```
public IEnumerable<Text> GetRecentTexts(int userId, int top, int start)
{
     var allUserTexts = _textRepo.Select(m => m.SenderId == userId || m.ReceiverId == userId); // Will get the moq return

     var recenteText = allUserTexts.Reverse();

     return recenteText.Skip(start).Take(top);
 }
```

The expected output is

```
  var expectedOutPut = new List<Text>()
    {
        new Text() {Id = 7, SenderId = 5, ReceiverId = 10},
        new Text() {Id = 6, SenderId = 5, ReceiverId = 4},
        new Text() {Id = 5, SenderId = 5, ReceiverId = 4}
    };
```

Assert Method using NUnit

```
var result = objectForTarget.GetRecentTexts(5, 3, 0);

Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutPut, result);
```

The problem is the Assert Method shows failed test with the message

```
<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Text]> with 3 elements, actual is <System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__24`1[Text]>
  Values differ at index [0]
  Expected: <Text>
  But was:  <Text>
```

I debugged the target method, and it returns the expected result but NUnit Assert says they are not the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably because `Text` is a class and you didn't override `Equals`, which means the equality test is referential equality.

Comment: I believe it fails because the type is different. One is IEnumerable<Text> and the other is List<Text>. Assert.AreEqual also compares the object type and that is why it is failing.

Comment: You want `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` assuming you have implemented equality for `Text`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assert.AreEqual` will compare the reference of the two lists which is different.

Use [CollectionAssert.AreEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx) for comparing collections

Then you will need to [override the Equals methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx) of `Text` or provide an IComparer

Answer (score 1):

It is correct as indicated in some comments and Ofir's answer that you have to override the Equals method of `Text`. Otherwise, `object.Equals` is used.

It is incorrect that you have to use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` It does nothing different from either `Assert.AreEqual` or `Assert.That(..., Is.EqualTo(...))`. `CollectionAssert` serves no purpose except that to make it easier for MsTest users to convert to NUnit.

It is also incorrect that the Type of the two collections need to be equal. NUnit compares the contents of arrays, collections, lists and enumerations based on their content.